# How to convert Holoviews graph to Bokeh 'model' in order to utilize more Bokeh features such as bokeh.models.GraphRenderer and node_renderer?

Tags: visualization, bokeh, networkx, graph-visualization, holoviews

I'm trying to create a directed graph using networkx and bokeh, however, I also want to show the arrows for each out-edge. I found that the Holoviews library has the ability to add a 'directed=true' parameter to its graph constructor. However, I also want to utilize Bokeh's design features such as adjusting node color/size based on previously set node-attributes. The latter only works if I use Bokeh's from_networkx() to get a bokeh.models.renderers.GraphRender object, and then use its attributes node_renderer and edge_renderer.

The issue is when using Holoviews' renderer to specify Bokeh as the backend, it returns a bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure instead of the GraphRenderer. Ultimately, I want to be know how to be able to control the node size/color based on some attributes possible through Bokeh, and simultaneously use Holoviews to display the arrowheads on each edge.

```
import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.io import show, output_file

# ... some code for I/O ...
G = nx.DiGraph(edgeList)   # Directed networkx graph

# Set Node/Edge attributes to display upon hover
numConnections = {k:v for k,v in G.out_degree()}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, numConnections, name='numConnections')

# Returns Holoviews graph
hvGraph = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout).opts(tools=['hover'], directed=True, arrowhead_length=0.01)
# Renders Holoviews graph into bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure
hvRendered = hv.render(hvGraph, 'bokeh')

output_file("out.html")
show(hvRendered)


# # The below code runs as expected using Bokeh only, and not Holoviews 
# # to produce the directed graph (without arrowed edges):

# from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle
# from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, BasicTicker
# import bokeh.models as bm
# from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
# from bokeh.models.graphs import NodesAndLinkedEdges, EdgesAndLinkedNodes


# # Returns GraphRenderer from bokeh.models.renderers.DateRenderer 
# graphRenderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout)

# mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=76, high=0)

# # Node size/color when unselected / selected / hover
# graphRenderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(
#     size='node_size',
#     fill_color= {'field': "numConnections", "transform": mapper},
#     fill_alpha=.8
# )
# graphRenderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(
#     size=25,
#     fill_color=Inferno6[4]
# )
# graphRenderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(
#     size=20,
#     fill_color=Inferno6[3]
# )

# # Edge size/color when unselected / selected / hover
# graphRenderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(
#     line_color="#CCCCCC",
#     line_alpha=0.8,
#     line_width=3
# )
# graphRenderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(
#     line_color=Inferno6[4],
#     line_width=4
# )
# graphRenderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(
#     line_color=Inferno6[3],
#     line_width=4
# )

# graphRenderer.node_renderer.data_source.data['numConnections'] = [v for k,v in 
    nx.get_node_attributes(G,'numConnections').items()]

# graphRenderer.selection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()
# graphRenderer.inspection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()

# bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, location=(0,0),     title='#connections')

# # Create Bokeh Plot
# plot = Plot(
#     plot_width=20,
#     plot_height=20,
#     x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1),
#     y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1)
# )

# plot.add_tools(
#     bm.HoverTool(tooltips=[("#connections", "@numConnections")]),
#     bm.TapTool(),
#     bm.BoxSelectTool()
# )
# plot.renderers.append(graphRenderer)

# output_file("bokeh.html")
# show(plot)
```

After rendering the Holoview graph into a Bokeh Figure (not a models.GraphRenderer), if I try to call the attribute node_renderer using the rendered Bokeh Figure object, it obviously throws an exception.

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                     File "holoview.py", line 106, in                                                                               hvRenderedGraph.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle()                                                         AttributeError: 'BokehRenderer' object has no attribute 'node_renderer'

Answer (score 1):

You can get the GraphRender object by following code:

```
from bokeh.models import GraphRenderer
gr = hvRendered.select_one(GraphRenderer)
```

then use `gr.node_renderer` and `gr.edge_renderer` to adjust the style.